# Viewing and analysing JSON log files

Tags: json, logging, viewer

I have a few JSON-based log files (all in the same format) that I would like to view and analyse in a consolidated way.

I.e., first I'd like to view the entries from all files at once, sorted by their timestamp (or an arbitrary other criterion, such as category, id, ... whatever).

Next, I'd like to be able to filter all those entries, including full-text search.

Last but not least, it would be interesting to analyse the logs automatically. Things such as: Event X always happens within 5 seconds after event Y (but the software shall automatically detect this, and point out anomalies).

Is there any software for this that you can recommend? Ideally, it should be a web-application, but a desktop app for OS X would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your files to loggly, or push them to logstash. Both provide a rich query language.